# Is there a compact connected Hausdorff space in which every non-empty $G_\delta$ set has non-empty interior?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, topological-groups, linear-orders

Q1. 
Is there a compact connected Hausdorff space (with at least two points) in which every non-empty $G_\delta$ set has non-empty interior? (Without the requirement for connectedness, every finite $T_1$ space is an example, and a more interesting example is the remainder of the Stone-Cech compactification of the integers, see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92905/an-example-of-topological-space-in-which-each-singleton-is-not-in-g-delta) and also [Parovicenko space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parovicenko_space).)

There are versions of the above question for LOTS 
(i.e. [linearly ordered topological spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology) with the *order* also called *open-interval* topology), and for topological groups.

Q2. 
Is there a compact connected LOTS in which every non-empty $G_\delta$ set has non-empty interior? (I believe the following is a restatement: Is there a compact connected LOTS which is not first-countable at any point?)

Q3. 
Is there a compact connected Hausdorff topological group in which every non-empty $G_\delta$ set has non-empty interior? (Such a group would necessarily have to be non-metrizable.)

Question 1 was inspired by the following [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215866/separation-in-compact-spaces) (in particular by my answer there). Questions 2 and 3 are related and I feel the answers (to all questions) are probably known, in that case would you please provide reference(s).

Edit. Thanks to @ChristianRemling for pointing out that I am interested in examples with at least 2 points. (It follows that such examples, being connected and normal, will have at least continuum many points.)

Edit. The following answer was posted by @Alessandro Vignati (who perhaps could not post it is a comment): "You should have a look at the Stone-Cech reminder of $[0,1)$. I suspect this may be an example of what you're looking for in Q1".

First thank you for the suggested answer. While I agree that the Stone-Cech *remainder* of $[0,1)$ (or of $[0,\infty)$) is an example to look at, and I had already taken a (brief) look at related papers, I could not deduce the answer, so I posted the above question. Perhaps I am overlooking something obvious, but at any rate unless I see a more specific reference to the suggested result, or a (sketch of) proof, I would not consider the above question answered. Here are a couple of links to papers related to the Stone-Cech remainder $H^*$ of the half-line $H=[0,\infty)$ (indeed $H^*$ is compact and connected, and perhaps satisfies the condition about $G_\delta$ sets I am asking about, but I do not quite see this part, even if I agree it is not something unreasonable to suspect): 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9805008.pdf and 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.0838.pdf

Comment: @JosephVanName Thank you ... I either didn't know or had forgotten this terminology, though I spent some time searching for $P$-spaces, but $P$-space is a too strong condition (I think when every $G_\delta$ set is itself open).

Comment: It was proved by Fine and Gillman that the remainder of a locally-compact realcompact space, e.g.[0,1), is an almost $P$-space. See N. Fine and L. Gillman, *Extensions of continuous functions in $\beta\mathbb{N}$*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 66 (1960) 376–381.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a proof of Alessandro Vignati's guess: Let $G_n$ be a decreasing sequence of nonempty open subsets of $X=\beta[0,1)\setminus[0,1)$. Choose $x\in\bigcap G_n$ - by assumption the intersection is nonempty. Then for each $n$ choose a pair of disjoint subsets of $\beta[0,1)$, namely $U_n\ni x$ and $V_n\supseteq X\setminus G_n$. They exist by normality of $\beta[0,1)$. Then we have $\bar U_n\cap X\subseteq G_n$. We may also assume that the sequence $U_n$ is decreasing. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ choose an open interval $I_n\subseteq [0,1)$ such that:

- $I_n\subseteq U_n$
- the supremum of  $I_n$ is less than $1$
- the infimum of $I_n$ is more than $1-{1\over n}$
- to make things more elegant we may assume that $I_n$ sits above $I_{n-1}$

Such $I_n$ always exists since $U_n\cap X$ nonempty forces $U_n\cap[0,1)$ to be unbouded ($X$ has an empty interior in $\beta[0,1)$). Note that for $n<m$ we have $I_m\subseteq U_m\subseteq U_n$.
Let $U=\bigcup I_n$ then for every $n$ there exists an $a<1$ such that $U\cap[a,1)\subseteq U_n$. Therefore $G=(\mathop{\rm int}\bar U)\cap X$ is contained in $\bigcap G_n$, and it is nonempty as $U$ is open and unbouded.

Answer (score 4):

It's not hard to construct a compact connected LOTS with this property.  Let $X_0$ be any countably saturated dense linear order, and let $X$ be its bounded Dedekind completion ("bounded" meaning also add points at $\pm\infty$).  Explicitly, such an $X_0$ can be constructed by a transfinite induction of length $\omega_1$, where at each stage you add a new point into every cut (even cuts for which a sup or inf exists).  Suppose $U_n$ is a sequence of open sets in $X$ and let $x\in\bigcap U_n$.  Assume $x\neq\pm\infty$; if $x=\pm\infty$ the argument is similar.  We can find a sequence of intervals $(a_n,b_n)\subseteq U_n$ with $a_n,b_n\in X_0$ and $$a_0<a_1<a_2<\dots<x<\dots<b_2<b_1<b_0.$$

Since $X_0$ is countably saturated, there exist $a,b\in X$ such that $a_n<a<b<b_n$ for all $n$.  Thus $\bigcap U_n$ contains the $(a,b)$ and has nonempty interior (note that $x$ itself might not be in the interior; it could be $\sup a_n$ or $\inf b_n$, but it can't be both).

Comment: I couldn't do the "but it can't be both" part on my own yesterday (using somewhat simpler but related ideas), thank you for being specific with the construction. I wasn't sure of the meaning of "countably saturated", [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model) suggests there are two versions of the definition, I assume you meant the version with "countable sets of parameters" rather than "finite parameter sets".

Answer (score 3):

The completely regular spaces $X$ such that every $G_{\delta}$ set has a non-empty interior are called almost $P$-spaces. The following facts will help you construct numerous examples of almost $P$-spaces.

Recall that a $P$-space is a completely regular space where every $G_{\delta}$-set is open. Therefore, the notion of an almost $P$-space is a weakening of the notion of a $P$-space.  If $X$ is locally compact and realcompact, then $\beta X\setminus X$ is an almost $P$-space (this fact generalizes the answer of Adam Przeździecki). A completely regular space $X$ is an almost $P$-space if and only if its Hewitt Realcompactification $\upsilon X$ is an almost $P$-space.

A product of spaces $X\times Y$ is an almost $P$-space if and only if both $X$ and $Y$ are almost $P$-spaces. It is easy to show that a dense subspace of an almost $P$-space is an almost $P$-space. However, a closed subspace of an almost $P$-space is not necessarily an almost $P$-space. In fact, every completely regular space can be embedded as a closed subspace of an almost $P$-space. If $B$ is a Boolean algebra, then the Stone space of $B$ is an almost $P$-space if and only if $B$ has no countable partitions. In particular, if $B$ is $\aleph_{1}$-saturated, then the Stone space $S(B)$ is an almost $P$-space. The papers 1,2 give more information on almost $P$-spaces (with the link to 2 provided by Mirko).

For question 2, an example of a totally ordered almost $P$-space is given in Proposition 2.3 of [2](http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v29/cjm1977v29.0284-0288.pdf).

1. [Almost P-spaces](http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/981133.pdf). Chang Il Kim.
   Commun. Korean Math. Soc. 18 (2003), No. 4, pp. 695–701
2. Ronnie Levy. [Almost-P-Spaces](http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v29/cjm1977v29.0284-0288.pdf). Can. J. Math., Vol. XXIX, No. 2, 1977, pp. 284-288

Comment: Thank you, I also found another [paper by Ronnie Levi](http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v29/cjm1977v29.0284-0288.pdf) about almost $P$-spaces

Comment: Mirko. Thanks for providing the link to that paper.

Comment: though I misspelled his name, should be Ronnie Levy. His definition is that in an almost P-space, $G_\delta$ sets have dense interiors (clearly he means dense in the $G_\delta$ set, and his version of the definition is equivalent to requiring that the interior be non-empty when the $G_\delta$ set is non-empty).

Answer (score 3):

I claim that no infinite compact group can be an almost $P$-space. In other words, in every compact group there is a nonempty $G_{\delta}$ that does not contain any nonempty open set.

Suppose that $G$ is an infinite compact group. Let $\mu$ be the Haar probability measure on $G$. I claim that every non-empty open subset of $G$ has positive measure. Suppose that $U\subseteq G$ is a non-empty open set. Then $G=\bigcup_{g\in G}Ug$, so by compactness, there are $g_{1},...,g_{n}$ with $G=Ug_{1}\cup... U g_{n}$. However, since $\mu(U)=\mu(Ug_{1})=...=\mu(Ug_{n})$, we conclude that $1=\mu(G)\leq\mu(Ug_{1})+...+\mu(Ug_{n})=n\mu(U)$, so $\mu(U)\geq\frac{1}{n}$. However, it is easy to construct a non-empty $G_{\delta}$ subset of $G$ with measure zero. Therefore $G$ is a non-empty $G_{\delta}$-set that does not contain any non-empty open set. A similar argument shows that every non-discrete locally compact abelian group is not an almost $P$-space.