# Measure with `somewhere dense' support

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff (but not necessarily metrizable) space. 
Is it always true that there exists a probability Borel measure $\mu$ and an open set $U$ such that any nonempty open set $V\subset U$ has positive measure?
Which additional hypothesis would help?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035823/existence-of-strictly-positive-probability-measures   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163684/existence-of-measures-assigning-positive-values-to-all-open-sets   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76751/existence-of-a-completely-supported-probability-measure  might be relevant

Comment: another thought: what if you take say a non-separable Hilbert space? Then any ball will contain uncountable many balls of smaller radius and you will not be able to assign a positive value to each of them

Comment: Well, I ask for compact. If we go for the weak topology (and I'm not even sure that in non-separable spaces that still gives a compact unit ball) then I don't see right away why any open set has unaccountably many (disjoint?) open subsets

Comment: I am sorry, I have overlooked the compactness condition. However Alaoglu Theorem guarantees weak compactness of any closed ball in the dual of any normed space. But again, this is probably useless, since small balls are nowhere dense in the big ball

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An almost $P$-space is a topological space where every nonempty $G_{\delta}$-set has a nonempty interior. By the answers to this [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/202063/22277), there exists compact almost $P$-spaces without any isolated points. However, I claim that if $X$ is a compact $P$-space and $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $X$, then for each nonempty open set $U$ there is a nonempty open subset $V\subseteq U$ with $\mu(V)=0$. Suppose that $U$ is a nonempty open subset of $X$. Then by induction, we can construct a sequence $(U_{n})_{n\in\omega}$ of open sets with $U_{0}\subseteq U,\overline{U_{n+1}}\subseteq U_{n}$ and where $\mu(U_{n+1})<\frac{1}{2}(\mu(U_{n}))$. Let $G=\bigcap_{n}U_{n}$. Then $G$ is a non-empty $G_{\delta}$-set with $\mu(G)=0$. However, since $X$ is an almost $P$-space, there is a nonempty open set $V$ with $V\subseteq G$. Clearly $\mu(V)=0$ but $\emptyset\neq V\subseteq U$.

Comment: Ah, I was hopping the answer was yes... Thanks for the simple example.

Comment: Also the space $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the almost P-space property. This is explicit, for instance, in Hindman and Strauss's book MR1642231, Theorem 3.36.

Answer (score 4):

By turning this result into a Boolean algebra problem, a result by Thomas Jech completely characterizes the compact zero-dimensional spaces which have measures $\mu$ so that $\mu(U)\neq\emptyset$ for each non-empty open set $U$.

> $\mathbf{Theorem}$ Let $B$ be a Boolean algebra. Then the following
>   are equivalent.
>
> 1. There is a finitely additive probability measure $\mu$ on $B$ so that $\mu(b)>0$ for each $b\in B^{+}$.
> 2. $B\setminus\{0\}$ is the countable union of some sets $(C_{n})_{n}$ where
>
>    i. For all $n$, there is some natural number $K(n)$ so that if
>      $R\subseteq C_{n}$ and $r\wedge s=0$ for $r,s\in R,r\neq s$, then $|R|\leq
>    K(n)$.
>
> ii. If $a\vee b\in C_{n}$, then $a\in C_{n+1}$ or $b\in C_{n+1}$.

The above theorem is proven in the paper [1](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-04/S0002-9939-07-09184-8/).

By transferring the above theorem via Stone duality to compact spaces, we obtain the following theorem.

> $\mathbf{Theorem}$
>
> Let $X$ be a compact zero-dimensional space and let $\mathcal{O}(X)$
>   be the collection of all open subsets of $X$. Then the following are
>   equivalent.
>
> 1. There exists a regular Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ so that $\mu(U)>0$ for each non-empty open set $U$.
> 2. There are subsets $C_{n}\subseteq\mathcal{O}(X)$ so that $\bigcup_{n}C_{n}=\mathcal{O}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and where
>
> i. There is some natural number $K(n)$ so that if $R\subseteq C_{n}$
>   and $U\cap V=\emptyset$ whenever $U,V\in R,U\neq V$, then $|R|\leq
>  K(n)$
>
> ii. if $U,V$ are open sets and $U\cup V\in C_{n}$, then $U\in C_{n+1}$
>   or $V\in C_{n+1}$.

Although the above theorem is stated in terms of compact zero-dimensional spaces it seems like the above result should hold for all compact Hausdorff spaces, but I am unaware of anyone who has worked out the details.

1. Thomas Jech. [Algebraic characterizations of measure algebras](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-04/S0002-9939-07-09184-8/)
   Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 136 (2008), 1285-1294

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the comments, a condition that would prevent a space from having such a measure is that every open subspace has uncountable [cellularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function). One can prove that a compact almost $P$-space without isolated points (see Joseph Van Name´s answer) has this property, thus obtaining a different proof that such a space does not admit a "somewhere-dense-supported" measure.

Let me give now a first-countable example (so it cannot be an almost $P$-space):

Let $X=Z^\omega$ where $Z$ is the Alexandroff duplicate of the Cantor space. Since $Z$ is first-countable, zero-dimensional and has a dense set of isolated points, $X$ is homogeneous by a result of D.B. Motorov announced in *Zero-dimensional and linearly ordered bicompacta: properties of homogeneity type*, Russ. Math. Surv. 44:6 (1989). Also, $X$ is compact and has uncountable cellularity (because $Z$ is compact and has uncountably many isolated points), which implies by homogeneity that any open subspace of $X$ has uncountable cellularity.